# Web scraping from multiple sites

Tags: python-3.x

i have a problem. I want to take the title of news article and the links from the article from multiple websites. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url_1 = "https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/home/en"
url_2 = "https://ec.europa.eu/info/news_en?pages=159399#news-block"

link = [url_1, url_2]
i = 1;

while i <= len(link):

    site = link[i-1]
    page = requests.get(site).text
    doc = bs(page, "html.parser")

    h3 = doc.find_all("h3", class_="listing__title")

    for b in h3:
        print(b.text)
        link = b.find_all("a")[0]["href"]
        if(link[0:5] != "https"): 
            link = "https://ec.europa.eu" + link
        print(link)
        print()
    i +=1
```

The problem is that i get an error for invalid link and i don't know how to solve the problem(i know that for the first link, i have to search for different tags but when i use if function so as to define which site i am searching, i don't get anything as a result). What can i do in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the variable `link` for two things. First you set it to the list of URLs and later, inside the `for b in h3` loop you overwrite it.

Change to

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url_1 = "https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/home/en"
url_2 = "https://ec.europa.eu/info/news_en?pages=159399#news-block"

links = [url_1, url_2]
i = 1;

while i <= len(links):

    site = links[i-1]
    page = requests.get(site).text
    doc = bs(page, "html.parser")

    h3 = doc.find_all("h3", class_="listing__title")

    for b in h3:
        print(b.text)
        link = b.find_all("a")[0]["href"]
        if(link[0:5] != "https"): 
            link = "https://ec.europa.eu" + link
        print(link)
        print()
    i +=1
```